# No analog audio output in X11

Tags: linux, x11, fedora, pyglet, pulseaudio

I'm working on a game written in pyglet. On my dev laptop using Fedora23 when I run it I can hear music/fx coming out my analog port, I have the default windows manager gnome3.

As test I installed it in a PC that will be used once it's finished.
We use a basic installation Fedora 23, with only X11 basic Desktop OpenBox (I guess), and all the packages to run the game.

Game starts but no audio at all, if I run "aplay /test.mp3" inside a terminal windows I can hear the music, it's like default audio is not set correctly inside X11.

Alsamixer has high volume, use pulseaudio as Card/Chip, I can select other card Realteck ALC283 still high volume, but still no sound, I'm logged in as root. I'm lost.

Comment: X11 doesn't manage any  audio support. For enabling hdmi audio on gnome, try gnome-control-center . If you have audio on your XSession, but not on your game, then it's probably a missing dependency on your game. Otherwise If you have console audio but not audio on your session, it's probably an access rights issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Inside Xterm I have sound using aplay command, but when it starts the game in full screen no sound, still from xterm. I don't want to use HDMI audio, it's also disabled in the BIOS, I use a normal jack port. I'm running it as root

Comment: Linux sound gives no two flying cents about X11, and vice versa. Run `aplay` in verbose mode, gather the output and look for error messages.

Comment: Please write your "RESOLVED" part in an actual answer and mark the question as solved. Otherwise the question will be "unanswered" forever and we like a tidy ship here at SO : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: I use avlib as library in my pyglet game. The game seems to start and work having the lib inside the same folder, but once moved to another PC I realize that it was not sufficient. After checking and comparing with my PC and the new one, I come across the FFMpeg library that after installed fixed my issue.